# Launch an external program python

Tags: python, external, launch

Hi I was asked to write a program which launch an external program test the program.
I wrote a python method in one file and imported it into another file and wrote test cases for it.

But I need to launch an external program.

Could someone please help me with what that is and how to do that?

Comment: Can you please show what have you tried ? please share your code with us

Comment: I have updated the code that I wrote in the question, please help. SUT is supposed to be an external application. I wrote it as a python program, I do not know what to do.

Comment: you might be interested in `nose` library

Comment: Thanks Mark, I actually looked at that post. subprocess is not working me on Mac with python 2.7. I tried with os.popen(python /path/to/fileToRun.py 1 1) by passing the arguments also, but it is not taking the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the os library. Comes with python, `import os` then you can use `os.system("unix terminal command")`  ex.

```
import os

os.system('python /path/to/fileToRun.py')
```

EDIT:

not sure why subprocess isn't working but popen should capture everything that is `print`ed with your other classes

```
result = os.popen('python /path/to/file.py').read()
print result
```

Comment: While technically correct, it is advised to use subprocess over os.system.

Comment: Good point, subprocesses expand on the functionality of the os library, thank you for that. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: The method in sut have two arguments and also I want to catch the stdout and stderr in a file log file.log. Do I need to use this: subprocess.check_output("python /pathtoSUT", 'a', 'b', stdout=subprocess.STDOUT, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=false)

Comment: I also need to check for the return value from the sut program

Comment: subprocess is not working me on Mac with python 2.7. I tried with os.popen(python /path/to/fileToRun.py 1 1) by passing the arguments also, but it is not returning the output by taking the arguments.

Comment: Try adding `os.popen(python /path/to/fileToRun.py 1 1).read()`. and You want the os command to write the log or you want python to write the log? Could you rephrase what you want this command to do?